# Apply vs Close, the clean way?

Tags: c#

On my Close/Ok button event I'm writing a lot of different variables.  What's the "cleanest" solution to handle both as opposed to copy/pasting it to the Apply button event?

The only actual difference is that Close/Ok does an Environment.exit.  It's probably close to 50 lines of code though.  Just trying to do it the right way.

Thanks in advance!

Full disclosure: I only started learning programming a month ago.  I'm sure there's a LOT wrong with my code.

```
private void doneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // actual end result osnap and right click values
    int findOvalue = 0;
    int findMvalue = 0;

    // OSNAP values
    int endpoint = 1;
    int midpoint = 2;
    int center = 4;
    int node = 8;
    int quadrant = 16;
    int intersection = 32;
    int insertion = 64;
    int perpendicular = 128;
    int tangent = 256;
    int nearest = 512;
    int apparentIntersection = 2048;
    int extension = 4096;
    int parallel = 8192;
    //int none = 0;
    //int clearAll = 1024;

    // find the OSNAP value
    if (cbxEndpoint.Checked) { findOvalue += endpoint; }
    if (cbxMidpoint.Checked) { findOvalue += midpoint; }
    if (cbxCenter.Checked) { findOvalue += center; }
    if (cbxNode.Checked) { findOvalue += node; }
    if (cbxQuadrant.Checked) { findOvalue += quadrant; }
    if (cbxIntersection.Checked) { findOvalue += intersection; }
    if (cbxInsertion.Checked) { findOvalue += insertion; }
    if (cbxPerpendicular.Checked) { findOvalue += perpendicular; }
    if (cbxTangent.Checked) { findOvalue += tangent; }
    if (cbxNearest.Checked) { findOvalue += nearest; }
    if (cbxApparent.Checked) { findOvalue  += apparentIntersection; }
    if (cbxExtension.Checked) { findOvalue += extension; }
    if (cbxParallel.Checked) { findOvalue += parallel; }
    if (cbxNone.Checked) { findOvalue = 0; }

    // Right Click values
    int defaultmode = 1;
    int editmode = 2;
    int commandactive = 4;
    int commandmode = 8;
    int menumode = 16;

    // find the right click value
    if (cbxRcDefault.Checked) { findMvalue += defaultmode; }
    if (cbxRcEdit.Checked) { findMvalue += editmode; }
    if (cbxRcCommandActive.Checked) { findMvalue += commandactive; }
    if (cbxRcCommand.Checked) { findMvalue += commandmode; }
    if (cbxRcMenu.Checked) { findMvalue += menumode; }


    // the value of the slider location.  3 to 100
    int zfValue = tbZoomFactor.Value;

    // file dialog
    int fdval = 0;
    if (cbxFileDialog.Checked) fdval = 1;

    // pick first
    int pfval = 0;
    if (cbxPickFirst.Checked) pfval = 1;

    // middle button pan
    int mbval = 0;
    if (cbxMbuttonPan.Checked) mbval = 1;

    // attribute required
    int attval = 0;
    if (cbxAttRequired.Checked) attval = 1;

    // paperspace background color
    int psval = 0;
    if (cbxPsBackground.Checked) psval = 256;

    string nL = Environment.NewLine;
    string ppValue = tbPromptPrefix.Text;

    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"N:\C3D Support\MySettings.txt");
    file.WriteLine("OSMODE," + findOvalue + nL + "SHORTCUTMENU," + findMvalue + nL + "ZOOMFACTOR," + zfValue + nL + "FILEDIA," + fdval + nL + "PICKFIRST," + pfval + nL + "MBUTTONPAN," + mbval + nL + "ATTREQ," + attval + nL + "BKGCOLORPS," + psval + nL + "CMDLNTEXT," + ppValue);
    file.Close();


    Environment.Exit(0);


}
```

Comment: Post your code. Otherwise, it would be hard to help.

Comment: Why not put the "actual code" in a function and call that from both places? (I recommend having very little code directly in event handlers.)

Comment: Edited for click event code

Comment: You got my +1. Don't be sad from -1s, and try more and more and ask your questions here at SO. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void doneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // call your new method here:
    NameYourMethodSomething();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}

private void otherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // call your method again:
    NameYourMethodSomething();
    Do_Something_Else_Whatever_You_Want_Here();
}

// put your stuffs here:
private void NameYourMethodSomething() {
    // actual end result osnap and right click values
    int findOvalue = 0;
    int findMvalue = 0;

    // OSNAP values
    int endpoint = 1;
    int midpoint = 2;
    int center = 4;
    int node = 8;
    int quadrant = 16;
    int intersection = 32;
    int insertion = 64;
    int perpendicular = 128;
    int tangent = 256;
    int nearest = 512;
    int apparentIntersection = 2048;
    int extension = 4096;
    int parallel = 8192;
    //int none = 0;
    //int clearAll = 1024;

    // find the OSNAP value
    if (cbxEndpoint.Checked) { findOvalue += endpoint; }
    if (cbxMidpoint.Checked) { findOvalue += midpoint; }
    if (cbxCenter.Checked) { findOvalue += center; }
    if (cbxNode.Checked) { findOvalue += node; }
    if (cbxQuadrant.Checked) { findOvalue += quadrant; }
    if (cbxIntersection.Checked) { findOvalue += intersection; }
    if (cbxInsertion.Checked) { findOvalue += insertion; }
    if (cbxPerpendicular.Checked) { findOvalue += perpendicular; }
    if (cbxTangent.Checked) { findOvalue += tangent; }
    if (cbxNearest.Checked) { findOvalue += nearest; }
    if (cbxApparent.Checked) { findOvalue  += apparentIntersection; }
    if (cbxExtension.Checked) { findOvalue += extension; }
    if (cbxParallel.Checked) { findOvalue += parallel; }
    if (cbxNone.Checked) { findOvalue = 0; }

    // Right Click values
    int defaultmode = 1;
    int editmode = 2;
    int commandactive = 4;
    int commandmode = 8;
    int menumode = 16;

    // find the right click value
    if (cbxRcDefault.Checked) { findMvalue += defaultmode; }
    if (cbxRcEdit.Checked) { findMvalue += editmode; }
    if (cbxRcCommandActive.Checked) { findMvalue += commandactive; }
    if (cbxRcCommand.Checked) { findMvalue += commandmode; }
    if (cbxRcMenu.Checked) { findMvalue += menumode; }


    // the value of the slider location.  3 to 100
    int zfValue = tbZoomFactor.Value;

    // file dialog
    int fdval = 0;
    if (cbxFileDialog.Checked) fdval = 1;

    // pick first
    int pfval = 0;
    if (cbxPickFirst.Checked) pfval = 1;

    // middle button pan
    int mbval = 0;
    if (cbxMbuttonPan.Checked) mbval = 1;

    // attribute required
    int attval = 0;
    if (cbxAttRequired.Checked) attval = 1;

    // paperspace background color
    int psval = 0;
    if (cbxPsBackground.Checked) psval = 256;

    string nL = Environment.NewLine;
    string ppValue = tbPromptPrefix.Text;

    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"N:\C3D Support\MySettings.txt");
    file.WriteLine("OSMODE," + findOvalue + nL + "SHORTCUTMENU," + findMvalue + nL + "ZOOMFACTOR," + zfValue + nL + "FILEDIA," + fdval + nL + "PICKFIRST," + pfval + nL + "MBUTTONPAN," + mbval + nL + "ATTREQ," + attval + nL + "BKGCOLORPS," + psval + nL + "CMDLNTEXT," + ppValue);
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Javad, much appreciated.  It should have been much more obvious.  I still get stuck on missing semi-colons/ syntax.  :(

Comment: @smakfactor1 u'r wellcome

Answer (score 2):

Refactor the variable writing into another method you call in both handlers.

Comment: Maybe you can include a small code example like this: http://pastebin.com/tWPjLa8B

Comment: @CompuChip I see no need for an example of something so straightforward.

Comment: Yeah, duh.  Sorry to waste anyones time.